# Troubleshooting Firebase npm errors

Tags: firebase, npm, firebase-tools

The error message I'm receiving is:

> npm ERR! code 1
> npm ERR! path C:\Users\YJ.cache\firebase\tools\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\protobufjs
> npm ERR! command failed
> npm ERR! command C:\Users\YJ.cache\firebase\runtime/shell.bat -c -- node scripts/postinstall
> npm ERR! '--'��(��) ���� �Ǵ� �ܺ� ����, ������ �� �ִ� ���α׷�, �Ǵ�
> npm ERR! ��ġ ������ �ƴմϴ�.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!   C:\Users\YJ\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-01-21T14_51_18_667Z-debug-0.log

I've attempted the following troubleshooting steps without success:

Running the command prompt as administrator
Clearing the npm cache using npm cache clean --force
Verifying internet connectivity
Checking Node.js version compatibility
Temporarily disabling antivirus/firewall
Reinstalling protobufjs using npm install -g protobufjs
I'd appreciate any further guidance or assistance in resolving this issue. Please let me know if you require additional information such as my operating system, Node.js version, or any other relevant details.

I followed the recommended instructions to install the Firebase CLI globally using the command npm install -g firebase-tools. I expected the installation to proceed smoothly and allow me to use the Firebase CLI tools. However, the process abruptly halted with an error message.

The error message, unfortunately in Korean, indicates a failure within the protobufjs module during its post-installation script. I don't understand the specifics of the error due to the language barrier, but it prevents me from completing the installation and utilizing the Firebase CLI.

I attempted several troubleshooting steps to resolve the issue. This included running the command as administrator, clearing the npm cache, verifying my internet connection, ensuring compatibility with my Node.js version, disabling antivirus/firewall, and even reinstalling the protobufjs module itself. Unfortunately, none of these efforts yielded any positive results, and the error persists.